Python - Password reset through mail server
I am trying to create a password reset feature in python using mail server. So the process is the same as every reset-password feature:

User clicks reset
User is asked to write the email that will be used to reset the password
An email arriving in their inbox to click a link in the format of http://127.0.0.1:5000/reset/eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImN. The token is refering to the exact email
And when they click the link they are redirected to the reset page where they enter their new password 2 times before pressing submit.

Where im having the problem is in the 4th step at the reset function where i receive the token and trying to update the database with the new credentials. the username = user_data['username']  successfully gets the email coming from the token.
The problem is that the code doesn't continuing at the if statement to update the database. It just bypasses it and goes directly to return render_template('reset.html')
@application.route('/reset/<token>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def reset(token):
    try:
        print(f"Received token: {token}")  
        print(f"Token type: {type(token)}")  

        try:
            user_data = s.loads(token, salt='password-reset', max_age=600)
            print(f"Decoded data type: {type(user_data)}")  
            print(f"Decoded data: {user_data}")  

            if not isinstance(user_data, dict) or 'username' not in user_data:
                raise ValueError("Decoded data is not a valid dictionary or missing 'username' key.")
            
            username = user_data['username']  
            print(username)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error decoding token: {e}") 
            flash("The reset link is invalid or has expired.")
            return redirect(url_for('forget'))  

        if request.method == 'POST':
            password = request.form['pass']
            confirm_password = request.form['pass2']

            if password != confirm_password:
                print('Both passwords have to be the same')
            else:
                
                conn = connect_db()
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute(f'UPDATE {USERS_TABLE} SET pass = %s WHERE username = %s', (password, username))
                conn.commit()

                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
                print("Your password has been reset successfully.")
                return redirect(url_for('login'))

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")  
        flash("An error occurred. Please try again.")
        return redirect(url_for('forget'))  

    return render_template('reset.html')

reset.html
<form name ="pythonProject1" action="{{ url_for('reset', token=value) }}" id="pp1" method="post">
  <h4 class="fw-bold mb-4" style="color: #92aad0;">Password reset</h4>
  <p class="mb-4" style="color: #45526e;">To reset your password , please fill in the text fields with your new password .</p>
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
     <div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <input value={{value}} type="email" id="mail" name="mail" class="form-control"  hidden/>

  </div>

  <div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" class="form-control" required />
    <label class="form-label" >new password</label>
  </div>

     <div class="form-outline mb-4">
    <input type="password" id="pass2" name="pass2" class="form-control" required />
    <label class="form-label" >repeat new password</label>
  </div>



  <div class="d-flex justify-content-end pt-1 mb-4">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded" type="submit" style="background-color: #92aad0;">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <hr>

</form>


Does your HTML form have method="POST"? Did you use a debugger (or prints) to confirm what you think the control flow is? And, if you did confirm it – i.e. that the branch if request.method == 'POST': is not taken – did you do anything to debug the condition, e.g. print(request.method == 'POST'), print(repr(request.method))?

@Ry- yes it does have method="post". added the reset.html in the post

Are you storing the password in the database in plain text? Unless this is just a toy code to learn the basics you should definitely not store bare passwords in your database. One unwanted access to the database and the passwords are gone.

There are several if statements, which one is not working as expected? Did you try printing the values that it's testing?
